# Removing an LI from a UL via Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I've got an unordered list populated by my MVC controller. In that unordered list, I have a button on each list item that lets the user remove that list item from the list.

The code works in the DB sense, but in the UI, the row still exists on the screen.

The workings:
html:

```
<div ng-hide="history.distLists.length == 0">
    <strong>Member of Distribution Lists:</strong>
    <div style="overflow-y: scroll; width: 100%; height: 120px;">
        <div ng-repeat="list in history.distLists">
            <span class="span9 offset1" style="min-height: 25px;">{{list.ListName}}</span>
            <span class="span1" style="min-height: 25px;">
                <button ng-show="history.currentUserIsRep" class="btn-link" ng-click="dlRemove({{list.ListId}})"><span class="btn-danger">&nbsp;X&nbsp;</span></button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the controller.js:

```
    $scope.dlRemove = function (listId) {
        api.dlRemove($routeParams.id, listId, function (result) {
            if (result.error) {
                notificationService.error('<h4>An error occurred removing the customer from the Distribution List.</h4>' + result.error);
            } else {
                $scope.history.distLists.splice(listId, 1);
                notificationService.success('Customer removed from Distribution List.');
            }
        });
    };
```

The splice is where the error gets thrown:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined
  at localhost/scripts/myPage/controllers.js:147:37

147 is the splice line, and 37 is "distLists".

My goal is just to have the dang row vanish after successfully removing it from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the fact that you create UL elements instead of LI's, I noticed that you pass `list.ListId` to the dlRemove function

Is `list.ListId` also the index or key to that `list` item in `distLists`? Unless it is so you would also need to pass `$index` to that function so it could call `splice` with `$index`.

I found Developer Tools and/or extensions such as Batarang and ng-inspector great in debugging scopes

Comment: Actually, the UL was a transition moment, and totally my bad: meant it to be a div. Updating the above with that now. As for list.ListId - that's the key for the data row, and passed into my dlRemove function. That part works wonderfully.

Comment: After studying up on the $index, I see what you mean entirely. Got it working now! Thanks!